# Test whether time of maximum differs across two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, group-differences

Suppose I have 10 repeated measurements of a quantitative variable $X$ of the individuals within two groups (let's call them A and B). For each group, I have the estimated means of variable $X$ at the 10 time points, that is, $$\hat{\mu}_1^A, \hat{\mu}_2^A, \ldots, \hat{\mu}_{10}^A$$ and $$\hat{\mu}_1^B, \hat{\mu}_2^B, \ldots, \hat{\mu}_{10}^B,$$
and the corresponding $10 \times 10$ variance-covariance matrices of these estimates.

Tests of $$H_0: \mu_t^A = \mu_t^B$$ (for $t = 1, \ldots, 10$) can be easily conducted using Wald-type tests (with an appropriate correction for multiple testing) with: $$z = \frac{\hat{\mu}_t^A - \hat{\mu}_t^B}{\sqrt{Var(\hat{\mu}_t^A) + Var(\hat{\mu}_t^B)}}.$$

Now I want to test whether the time point of the maximum within each group differs across the two groups. I suppose the null hypothesis could be written as $$H_0: t = t' \; \text{for} \max({\mu}_t^A) \; \text{and} \max({\mu}_{t'}^B).$$ What would be a way of testing that?

**EDIT**: Some R code to simulate data to play with.

```
library(MASS)

### number of individuals in the two groups
n1 <- 50
n2 <- 50

### assume a flat trajectory with a single peak at times 4 and 6 in the respective groups
mu1 <- rep(0,10)
mu2 <- rep(0,10)
mu1[4] <- 1
mu2[6] <- 1

### make the raw data autocorrelated with an AR1 structure
V1 <- 5 * toeplitz(ARMAacf(ar=.7, lag.max=9))
V2 <- 5 * toeplitz(ARMAacf(ar=.7, lag.max=9))

### simulate raw data
X1 <- mvrnorm(n1, mu1, V1)
X2 <- mvrnorm(n2, mu2, V2)

### observed means over time in each group
m1 <- apply(X1, 2, mean)
m2 <- apply(X2, 2, mean)

### find time of the maximum mean in each group
tmax1 <- which(m1 == max(m1))
tmax2 <- which(m2 == max(m2))

### plot means over time in each group
plot(1:10, m1,  type="o", pch=19, ylim=range(c(m1,m2)), col="red", xlab="Time", ylab="Mean")
lines(1:10, m2, type="o", pch=19, ylim=range(c(m1,m2)), col="blue")
points(tmax1, max(m1), pch=19, cex=2, col="red")
points(tmax2, max(m2), pch=19, cex=2, col="blue")
```

And an example of what the resulting plot looks like.

[image: figure of means over time in two groups]

Comment: I'd think bootstrapping or a permutation test would probably work. There's probably a more parametric approach using order statistics as well, though I'll pass on that to someone with more knowledge.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are not looking for the *distribution* of each group's individual maximum times, right? (For which you could simply tabulate how many participants in each group had their maximum at $t=1$, at $t=2$, ... and then do a chi-squared test.) Instead, you are averaging values per group and looking for the maximum times of these averages per group, right? Then I'd agree with @Affine that a bootstrap (stratified by individuals) should probably work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I considered using resampling methods, but the devil is in the details (how to stratify, discreteness of the statistic of interest). I have added some R code to simulate some data. How exactly would you go about doing the bootstrapping?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not entirely sure whether I found an *answer*... but my idea won't fit into a comment. So I'll post and see what the smarter people here point out.

As I commented above, I'd bootstrap the max time within each group, but stratified by individual - by resampling *rows* of `X1` and `X2`:

```
library(boot)
b1 <- boot(X1,statistic=function(X,index)which.max(apply(X[index,],2,mean)),10000)
b2 <- boot(X2,statistic=function(X,index)which.max(apply(X[index,],2,mean)),10000)
```

Then we can look at the distribution of the differences in the bootstrapped maxima:

```
foo <- b1$t-b2$t
ecdf(foo)(0)
hist(foo,breaks=seq(-10.5,10.5))
```

[image: histogram]

Now, the ecdf at zero tells us that 96.89% of differences are less than zero, which in some circles would be enough to claim $p<0.05$ and call it a day ;-) However, I *really* don't understand where the two peaks in the histogram come from. Does anybody have an idea?

(Fun question, anyway...)

---

EDIT: just for kicks, here is the other approach that could reasonably be taken - tabulate the max times for each individual by group and perform a $\chi^2$ test:

```
incidence <- cbind(
    table(factor(apply(X1,1,which.max),levels=1:10)),
    table(factor(apply(X2,1,which.max),levels=1:10)))
chisq.test(incidence)
```

Comment: I believe a parametric bootstrap may be called for here in order to respect the covariance structure mentioned in the question.

Comment: Stephan's code bootstraps individuals, keeping the repeated observations within individuals intact. So, the covariance structure is being preserved.

Comment: A bit of a follow-up to this. I did a simulation study (based on the code in my question and the code of Stephan for the boostrapping) to examine how well this approach works. I used 10,000 iterations with 10,000 bootstrap replicates in each iteration (took a while to complete). In each iteration, I checked whether the 95% percentile bootstrap CI contained the value 0 (if not, reject). When the null is true (peak at $t=5$ in both groups), the coverage rate was 100% (i.e., not a single rejection). With the null false (as in my code), the rejection rate was .22.

Comment: So, the approach appears to be overly conservative. It is a possible approach (thank you for the suggestion!), but I would love to see something that is directly based on the means and var-cov matrices (as suggested by @Affine, maybe something based on order statistics).